# I2C1 busy flag always high STM32F103RB

Tags: i2c, stm32f103

I finished my I2C peripheral drivers and I would like to test it with my BH1750 sensor but I am having an issue. When I initialize the I2C1 peripheral, everything is smooth but then I notice that the busy flag is always high and it does not go low. When I generate a start condition, the start flag does not go high and I assume it is due to the busy flag. I am not sure why it is doing this and I know it isn't an issue with my sensor because my sensor works with HAL code.

```c
#include "stm32f103rb_i2c_driver.h"

static void I2C_GenerateStartCondition(I2C_RegDef_t *pI2Cx);
static void I2C_ExecuteAddressPhaseRead(I2C_RegDef_t *pI2Cx, uint8_t SlaveAddr);
static void I2C_ClearADDRFlag(I2C_RegDef_t *pI2Cx);
static void I2C_GenerateStopCondition(I2C_RegDef_t *pI2Cx);
static void I2C_ExecuteAddressPhaseWrite(I2C_RegDef_t *pI2Cx, uint8_t SlaveAddr);

static void I2C_GenerateStartCondition(I2C_RegDef_t *pI2Cx)
{
    pI2Cx->CR1 |= ( 1 << 8);
}

static void I2C_ExecuteAddressPhaseRead(I2C_RegDef_t *pI2Cx, uint8_t SlaveAddr)
{
    SlaveAddr = SlaveAddr <<1;
    SlaveAddr &= ~(1); //Slave addr + r/w bit
    pI2Cx->DR = SlaveAddr;
}

static void I2C_ExecuteAddressPhaseWrite(I2C_RegDef_t *pI2Cx, uint8_t SlaveAddr)
{
    SlaveAddr = SlaveAddr <<1;
    SlaveAddr |= (1); //Slave addr + r/w bit
    pI2Cx->DR = SlaveAddr;
}

static void I2C_ClearADDRFlag(I2C_RegDef_t *pI2Cx)
{
    uint32_t dummyRead = pI2Cx->SR1;
    dummyRead = pI2Cx->SR2;
    (void)dummyRead;

}

static void I2C_GenerateStopCondition(I2C_RegDef_t *pI2Cx)
{
    pI2Cx -> CR1 |= (1<<9);
}

void I2C_ManageAcking(I2C_RegDef_t *pI2Cx, uint8_t EnorDi)
{
    if(EnorDi==I2C_ACK_ENABLE)
    {
        pI2Cx->CR1 |= (1<<10);
    }else
    {
        pI2Cx->CR1 &= ~(1<<10);
    }
}

void I2C_PeripheralControl(I2C_RegDef_t *pI2Cx, uint8_t EnOrDi)
{
    if(EnOrDi == ENABLE)
    {
        pI2Cx -> CR1 |= (1 << 0);

    }else
    {
        pI2Cx -> CR1 &= ~(1<<0);
    }
}

void I2C_PeriClockControl(I2C_RegDef_t *pI2Cx, uint8_t EnOrDi)
{
    if (EnOrDi == ENABLE)
    {
        if (pI2Cx == I2C1)
        {
            I2C1_PCLK_EN();
        }else if (pI2Cx == I2C2)
        {
        I2C2_PCLK_EN();
        }
    }else
    {
        if (pI2Cx == I2C1)
        {
            I2C1_PCLK_DI();
        }else if (pI2Cx == I2C2)
        {
        I2C2_PCLK_DI();
        }
    }
}

uint32_t RCC_GetPLLOutputClock()
{
    return 0;
}

uint16_t AHB_PreScaler[8] = {2,4,8,16,128,256, 512};
uint16_t APB1_PreScaler[8] = {2,4,8, 16};

uint32_t RCC_GetPCLK1Value(void)
{
    uint32_t pclk1, SystemClk;
    uint8_t clksrc, temp, ahbp, apb1p;

    clksrc = ((RCC -> CFGR >> 2)) & 0x3;

    if(clksrc == 0)
    {
        SystemClk = 8000000;

    }else if (clksrc == 1)
    {
        SystemClk = 16000000;

    }else if (clksrc == 2)
    {
        SystemClk = RCC_GetPLLOutputClock();
    }

    temp = (RCC -> CFGR >> 4) & 0xF;

    if (temp<8)
    {
        ahbp = 1;

    }else
    {
        ahbp = AHB_PreScaler[temp-8];
    }

    temp = (RCC -> CFGR >> 10) & 0x7;

    if (temp<4)
    {
        apb1p = 1;

    }else
    {
        ahbp = APB1_PreScaler[temp-4];
    }

    pclk1 = (SystemClk/ahbp) / apb1p;

    return pclk1;
}

/* Init and De-init */
void I2C_Init(I2C_Handle_t *pI2CHandle)
{
    uint32_t tempreg = 0;

    //enable clock
    I2C_PeriClockControl(pI2CHandle->pI2Cx, ENABLE);

    //ACK control
    tempreg |= pI2CHandle->I2C_Config.I2C_ACKControl << 10;
    pI2CHandle->pI2Cx->CR1 = tempreg;

    //FREQ
    tempreg = 0;
    tempreg |= RCC_GetPCLK1Value()/1000000U;
    pI2CHandle->pI2Cx->CR2 = (tempreg & 0x3F);

    //device own address
    tempreg |= pI2CHandle -> I2C_Config.I2C_DeviceAddress << 1;
    tempreg |= (1<<14);
    pI2CHandle -> pI2Cx -> OAR1 = tempreg;

    //CCR calc
    uint16_t ccr_value = 0;
    tempreg = 0;

    if(pI2CHandle -> I2C_Config.I2C_SCLSpeed <= I2C_SCL_SPEED_SM)
    {
        //standard mode
        ccr_value = RCC_GetPCLK1Value()/(2*pI2CHandle -> I2C_Config.I2C_SCLSpeed);
        tempreg |= (ccr_value & 0xFFF);
    }else
    {
        //fast mode
        tempreg |= (1<<15);
        tempreg |= (pI2CHandle -> I2C_Config.I2C_FMDutyCycle << 14);

        if(pI2CHandle->I2C_Config.I2C_FMDutyCycle == I2C_FM_DUTY_2)
        {
            ccr_value = RCC_GetPCLK1Value()/(3*pI2CHandle -> I2C_Config.I2C_SCLSpeed);
        }else
        {
            ccr_value = RCC_GetPCLK1Value()/(25*pI2CHandle -> I2C_Config.I2C_SCLSpeed);
        }

        tempreg |= (ccr_value & 0xFFF);
    }
    pI2CHandle -> pI2Cx->CCR = tempreg;

    //TRISE
    if (pI2CHandle -> I2C_Config.I2C_SCLSpeed <= I2C_SCL_SPEED_SM)
    {

        tempreg = (RCC_GetPCLK1Value() / 1000000U) + 1;

    }else
    {
        tempreg = ((RCC_GetPCLK1Value() * 300) / 1000000000U) + 1;

    }
    pI2CHandle -> pI2Cx->TRISE = (tempreg & 0x3F);

}

void I2C_DeInit(I2C_RegDef_t *pI2Cx)
{
    if(pI2Cx == I2C1)
            {
                I2C1_REG_RESET();
            }else if (pI2Cx == I2C2)
            {
                I2C2_REG_RESET();
            }

        I2C_PeripheralControl(pI2Cx, DISABLE);
}

uint8_t I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2C_RegDef_t *pI2Cx, uint32_t FlagName)
{
    if(pI2Cx->SR1 & FlagName)
    {
        return FLAG_SET;
    }
    return FLAG_RESET;
}

void I2C_MasterSendData(I2C_Handle_t *pI2CHandle, uint8_t *pTxbuffer, uint32_t Len, uint8_t SlaveAddr, uint8_t Sr)
{
    //Start condition
    I2C_GenerateStartCondition(pI2CHandle -> pI2Cx);

    //wait until SB set
    while(! I2C_GetFlagStatus(pI2CHandle->pI2Cx,I2C_SB_FLAG));

    //Send Addr of slave
    I2C_ExecuteAddressPhaseWrite(pI2CHandle ->pI2Cx,SlaveAddr);

    //confirm completion of address phase
    while(! I2C_GetFlagStatus(pI2CHandle->pI2Cx,I2C_ADDR_FLAG));

    //clear addr flag
    I2C_ClearADDRFlag(pI2CHandle->pI2Cx);

    //send data for len
    while(Len >0)
    {
        while( !I2C_GetFlagStatus(pI2CHandle -> pI2Cx, I2C_TXE_FLAG));
        pI2CHandle->pI2Cx->DR = *pTxbuffer;
        pTxbuffer++;
        Len--;
    }

    //wait for TXE=1 and BTF = 1 before stop

    while(! I2C_GetFlagStatus(pI2CHandle->pI2Cx,I2C_TXE_FLAG));
    while(! I2C_GetFlagStatus(pI2CHandle->pI2Cx,I2C_BTF_FLAG));

    //generate stop
    if(Sr == 0)
    {
        I2C_GenerateStopCondition(pI2CHandle->pI2Cx);
    }
}

void I2C_MasterReceiveData(I2C_Handle_t *pI2CHandle, uint8_t *pRxBuffer, uint8_t Len, uint8_t SlaveAddr, uint8_t Sr)
{
    //START condition
    I2C_GenerateStartCondition(pI2CHandle->pI2Cx);

    //confirm start generation
    while(! I2C_GetFlagStatus(pI2CHandle->pI2Cx,I2C_SB_FLAG));

    //Send address
    I2C_ExecuteAddressPhaseRead(pI2CHandle ->pI2Cx,SlaveAddr);

    //wait until addr phase is completed
    while(! I2C_GetFlagStatus(pI2CHandle->pI2Cx,I2C_ADDR_FLAG));

    if (Len == 1)
    {
        //disable acking
        I2C_ManageAcking(pI2CHandle->pI2Cx, I2C_ACK_DISABLE);

        //generate stop condition
        if(Sr == 0)
        {
            I2C_GenerateStopCondition(pI2CHandle->pI2Cx);
        }

        //clear addr flag
        I2C_ClearADDRFlag(pI2CHandle->pI2Cx);

        //wait until rxne is 1
        while( !I2C_GetFlagStatus(pI2CHandle -> pI2Cx, I2C_RXNE_FLAG));

        //read data into buffer
        *pRxBuffer = pI2CHandle -> pI2Cx->DR;

        return;
    }
    if (Len > 1)
    {
        //clear addr flag
        I2C_ClearADDRFlag(pI2CHandle->pI2Cx);

        //read data until len ==0
        for (uint32_t i = Len; i>0; i--)
        {
            // wait until rxne ==1
            while( !I2C_GetFlagStatus(pI2CHandle -> pI2Cx, I2C_RXNE_FLAG));

            if (i==2)
            {
                //clear ack
                I2C_ManageAcking(pI2CHandle->pI2Cx, I2C_ACK_DISABLE);

                //generate stop condition
                if(Sr == 0)
                {
                    I2C_GenerateStopCondition(pI2CHandle->pI2Cx);
                }

            }

            //read data into buffer
            *pRxBuffer = pI2CHandle -> pI2Cx->DR;

            //increment buffer address
            pRxBuffer++;
        }
    }

    //re-enable acking
    if(pI2CHandle -> I2C_Config.I2C_ACKControl == I2C_ACK_ENABLE)
    {
        I2C_ManageAcking(pI2CHandle->pI2Cx, I2C_ACK_ENABLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the HAL works, see what you are doing differently. And if you implemented all the workarounds in the Errata. How do you use your functions? Have you debugged where it goes wrong? Have you thought of implementing error handling? You can't expect the bus to be in a state you can send a start, if for example MCU was reading data from chip and MCU reset button is pushed, the slave might wait for next clock and drive data wire low.